# How to detect and replace the transaction details that stored in local when user retry the transaction with higher price using Metamask

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, etherscan

For a web application i stored the transaction id of an activity. if the user retry the transaction with a higher gas price in metamask(in case of the transaction take too long, metamask gives this option), is there is any possibility to replace the current transaction id that i stored with new one. how can detect this retry. is there is any web3 method for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same transaction to be carried out but just with a higher gas price, you won't need to replace the transaction ID as that doesn't change.

Calling a function in your front end with `web3.js` you would use this piece of code

```
   function functionYouWantToCall() {
        web3.eth.getAccounts(function(error, result) {
        web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {from:web3.eth.accounts[0],
            to: YourContractAddress,
            value:  "0", 
            data: "0xTheHashOfTheFuctionYouWantToCall"
                }, function(err, result) {
          if (!err)
            console.log(error); 
        });
    });

    }
```

To find the information you should put in the data field, go to Remix and then on the run tab select details, scroll down to function hashes and select paste in the hash of the function you wish to call with `0x` in front of it. Also make sure to enter your own contracts address in the contract address feild

Comment: but the retry generates new transaction id, and the old one will always in pending state, after some time this id will delete from etherscan, any solution to get the new id?

Comment: Are you doing this with a smart contract that's been uploaded to the blockchain?

Comment: yes. doing with an uploaded smartcontract

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully this should help